# Azure Data Factory - pass parameter to SAP HANA CDS view

Tags: azure-data-factory, hana, gigya

Does anyone know, how to pass parameter from Azure Data Factory data flow to SAP HANA view?

The task is to filter BSIK to GJAHR through DataFlow activity and SAP CDC scenario with full load at every time.

1. Based on GJAHR, I created view ZBSIKTST, based on BSIK:

   ```
   define view ZBSIKTSTv
   with parameters p_gjahr:gjahr
   as select from bsik
   {
    key bukrs,
    key lifnr,
    key umsks,
    key umskz,
    key augdt,
    key augbl,
    key zuonr,
    key gjahr,
    key belnr,
    key buzei
   }
   where gjahr = :p_gjahr
   ```
2. Tried to put the parameter in SAP CDC Dataset  with many ways, no positive results.

Thanks!

Comment: Where did you create parameter? In ADF pipeline or dataflow parameter? Can you show how you passed parameter in the query ? and the error message you got

Comment: I put the parameter P_GJAHR as string with default value = 2023 on source dataset parameter section, bind the right ODP context and CDS view:  

https://pasteboard.co/YyvPNb7dERf6.png  
https://pasteboard.co/xgUFP78zFiC6.png  

Then in dataflow on source1 module, chose dataset refered:  

https://pasteboard.co/UkQAqATAIgoV.png  

On active cluster, I tried to preview data, I got an error:  

 fail to preview data with error code: 27153, with reason: Sap Odp operation 'PreviewOdpData' failed. Error Number: '007', error message: 'Error while accessing data:'